# How to have d3 tickFormat of (day, time) but only show time if day is the same?

Tags: d3.js

I have a D3 graph where I want an axis to have ticks of day, time (e.g. "Jan 20, 12:00am").

This is easy enough I just to:

```
xAxis.tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b %-d, %-I:%M%p'));
```

This produces

- Jan 20, 12:00am
- Jan 20, 12:00pm
- Jan 21, 12:00am
- Jan 21, 12:00pm
- etc...

What I would like it to do is when the day is the same as the previous tick, don't show the day and just show the time. (basically only show the part that's different)

- Jan 20, 12:00am
- 12:00pm
- Jan 21, 12:00am
- 12:00pm

Is this possible? As far as I can tell the callback you provide to tickFormat isn't given the value supplied to the previous function. It gives you the current value, the tick index, and some third number (not sure what that's for)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In D3 v3, you can use `axis.scale().ticks()` to access the previous tick, and use a custom `tickFormat` to check that and return the appropriate text:

```
var data = [new Date("2016/01/01"), new Date("2016/01/03")];

var scale = d3.time.scale()
  .domain(d3.extent(data))
  .range([0, 400]);

var timeFormatWithDate = d3.time.format("%b %-d, %-I:%M%p");
var timeFormatWithoutDate = d3.time.format("%-I:%M%p");

var axis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(scale)
  .orient("left")
  .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
    var ticks = axis.scale().ticks();
    if (i > 0 && ticks[i - 1].getDay() === d.getDay()) {
      return timeFormatWithoutDate(d);
    } else {
      return timeFormatWithDate(d);
    }
  });

d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 420)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(200, 10)")
  .data(data)
  .call(axis);
```

[image: Screenshot]

https://jsfiddle.net/Dogbert/gy5h364g/3/

Comment: Beautiful, upvoted. It works the same with just `return timeFormatWithDate(d)` and `return timeFormatWithoutDate(d)` .

Comment: @GerardoFurtado ah yeah, I originally solved this for d3 v4 and then rewrote for v3 after realising OP was using v3 and then forgot to clean up the code. Here's the v4 implementation if anyone is interested: https://jsfiddle.net/Dogbert/gy5h364g/

Comment: Slight correction here, you want to use `d.getDate()` rather than `d.getDay()`